# How to package the project using wheel in python

Tags: python, python-wheel, requirements.txt

I am not aware about wheel. I have requirement.txt file. There is one more thing - wheel. I confused about wheel and requirement.txt. I want package my project using wheel.How I can package my project using wheel so I can easy install all the project dependencies using one shot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my git to make a new project with setup.py file and after that run

```
pip install -e .
```

to make a new version of your project

https://github.com/adouani/create_template

EDIT

Example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
with open(os.path.join(here, 'README.txt')) as f:
    README = f.read()
with open(os.path.join(here, 'CHANGES.txt')) as f:
    CHANGES = f.read()
with open(os.path.join(here, 'external_requirements.txt')) as f:
    requires = f.readlines()

# on sépare la définition des dépendances internes des dépendances externes

requires.extend([
   ......
])
setup(
    name='..........',
    version='0.1.0.dev0',
    description='',
    long_description=README + '\n\n' + CHANGES,
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python",
        "Framework :: Pyramid",
        "Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP",
        "Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP :: WSGI :: Application",
    ],
    author='............',
    author_email='',
    url='',
    keywords='web wsgi bfg pylons pyramid',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=requires,
    message_extractors={'.': [
        ('ihm/**.py', 'lingua_python', None),
        ('ihm/**.pt', 'lingua_xml', None),
        ('ihm/**.html', 'html', None),
        ('ihm/**.py', 'python', None),
        ('ihm/**.js', 'js', None),
    ]},
    dependency_links=[
        '............',
        '.............',
        'git+http://............#egg=ihm-0.7.0',
    ],
)
```

Comment: It is creating a dummy project. I want all my project dependencies.

Comment: Yes, you put then all your files into the project and your dependencies in external file and run the command pip install -e .
for internal package use dependency_links=[.. ] in setup.py and add require.extend([...])

Comment: it is good but I need the wheel implementation. I have the requirement of to use wheel to package the project.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know wheel